# Specifying part of an image to be used in cm

Tags: graphics, crop

I have a multipage pdf document and would like to include only the upper part (say 3cm down and 2cm right from upper left corner) of a given page. Including part of a single page can be done with `\includegraphics`,

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics*[page=7,width=\textwidth,viewport=30 30 120 120]{file.pdf}

\end{document}
```

but how do change the units to something like cm or inches?

Comment: Nobody keeps you from putting the unit `cm` after the numbers.

Comment: use it, e.g.: `viewport=1cm 1cm 4cm 5cm`

Comment: that simple, who would have thought...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd measure the graphics (original size) and then trim it. I assume that you want to enlarge that zone to the text width

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\sbox{0}{\includegraphics{filename}}
\setlength{\dimen6}{\wd0}\setlength{\dimen8}{\ht0}
\includegraphics[%
  width=\textwidth,
  trim=0 {\dimexpr\dimen8-3cm\relax} {\dimexpr\dimen6-2cm\relax} 0,
  clip]{filename}
\caption{Particular of the upper left corner of the page}
\end{figure}
```

The four parameters for `trim=` are the amount to be trimmed on the left, below, on the right and above respectively. With `clip` you are telling `pdftex` to not show the trimmed part.

Note that this doesn't require measuring manually the graphics. However, you find the bounding box information in the log file.

The scratch registers used are `\dimen6` and `\dimen8` that are not used by `graphicx.sty`; one must, however, check that the result is what's expected. The safest way would be to define two lengths for the purpose.

Comment: What are the `\dimenX`'s in `{\dimexpr\dimenX-Ycm\relax}` if I now also want to clip off the top and the left? Where can i find documentation on this?